# using command cmposer.phar install

Tags: php, composer-php, installation

I have accidentally used `open with` notepad on my composer.phar to notepad and it looks like this:

[image: iamge]

Now problem is when i run composer.phar install in cmd na get this

[image: iamge2]

Now I tried to use

1. Right Click
2. Properties
3. Default but I cant find it

***What is the proper way to return the composer.phar to its default way***

`UPDATE`

> When i run composer.phar install in cmd it opens the file in notepad

Answer (score 0):

just googling for "windows remove extension association" shows this:

https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-set-default-programs-and-file-types-in-windows-10/

Comment: apparently there is no composer.phar in the on the programs